# Cusparse status mapping error while using cuda constant memory

Tags: cuda

I am using cuda cusparse library to deal with sparse matrices and I need to perform matrix vector multiplication (cusparseDcsrmv function). I have a sparse matrix d_A in csr format and when I call this function with vector d_x allocated in global device memory everything works correctly. But while I want to use a vector residing in constant device memory I've got an error: CUSPARSE_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR
The documentation says that the usual solution is to unbind any previously bound textures but it has nothing do to with what I'm doing.

Does anyone know what's going on?

```
const int ONES_SIZE = 5400;
__constant__ static double ONES_DEV[ONES_SIZE];

const cusparseDirection_t dirA_row = CUSPARSE_DIRECTION_ROW;
const cusparseOperation_t NON_TRANS = CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE;

int main(){    
    cudaSetDevice(0);

    int m = ONES_SIZE; int n = 2500;
    double * HOST_ONES, *A, *d_A, *d_result;
    HOST_ONES = (double*) malloc(ONES_SIZE*sizeof(double));
    for (int i=0; i<ONES_SIZE; i++)
        HOST_ONES[i] = 1.0;
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(ONES_DEV, HOST_ONES, ONES_SIZE*sizeof(double), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    A = (double *) calloc(m*n, sizeof(double));
    // populate matrix A
    for(int i=0;i<1000; i++)
        A[i*2] = 1.5;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, m*n*sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, m*n*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cusparseHandle_t cusparse_handle = 0;
    cusparseMatDescr_t descrA=0;
    int *nnzTotal, *nnzPerRow, *csrRowPtrA, *csrColIndA;
    double* csrValA;
    int lda = m;
    const double positive = 1.0;
    const double zero = 0.0;

    cusparseCreate(&cusparse_handle);
    cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA);
    cusparseSetMatType(descrA, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL);
    cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrA, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);

    nnzTotal = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&nnzPerRow, m*sizeof(int));
    cusparseDnnz(cusparse_handle, dirA_row, m, n, descrA, d_A, lda, nnzPerRow, nnzTotal);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&csrValA, (*nnzTotal)*sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&csrRowPtrA, (m+1)*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&csrColIndA, (*nnzTotal)*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_result, n*sizeof(double));

    // MATRIX CONVERSE FROM DENSE TO SPARSE
    cusparseDdense2csr(cusparse_handle, m, n, descrA, d_A, lda, nnzPerRow, csrValA, csrRowPtrA, csrColIndA);

    // MATRIX VECTOR MULTIPLICATION
    cusparseDcsrmv(cusparse_handle, NON_TRANS, m, n, *nnzTotal, &positive, descrA, csrValA, csrRowPtrA, csrColIndA, ONES_DEV, &zero, d_result);
```

Comment: You don't want to use constant memory for `x`. Constant memory requires *uniform* access to be beneficial. The underlying access pattern for the vector `x` when performing the matrix-vector product `Ax` will not be uniform. *Uniform* means all threads in a warp will access the same location in any given cycle. This is not the case with sparse matrix-vector product. In general, the use of constant memory with cuSparse is not an expected use case. The [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#introduction) lists the expected copy APIs, and `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` is not listed

Comment: I would risk a wild guess: It might be that cuSparse is using textures to benefit from some form of cache when performing sparse matrix x vector multiply. In which case, it would bind the vector data to a texture to speed-up this operation. Of course, you may not bind a pointer to constant memory on a texture.

Answer (score 1):

Taking your code sample and running it with Visual Profiler, while tracking API calls, I get the following:

[image: Visual profiler snapshot]

Where cusparse method is making a call to cudaBindTexture. Constant memory being a special type of memory, binding a texture to it seems impossible, even though not documented.