# How can I accelerate a sparse matrix by dense vector product, currently implemented via scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.dot, using CUDA?

Tags: python, matrix, cuda, gpu, sparse-matrix

My ultimate goal is to accelerate the computation of a matrix-vector product in Python, potentially by using a CUDA-enabled GPU. The matrix A is about 15k x 15k and sparse (density ~ 0.05), and the vector x is 15k elements and dense, and I am computing Ax. I have to perform this computation many times, so making it as fast as possible would be ideal.

My current non-GPU “optimization” is to represent A as a scipy.sparse.csc_matrix object, and then simply computing A.dot(x), but I was hoping to speed this up on a VM with a couple NVIDIA GPUs attached, and using only Python if possible (i.e. not writing out the detailed kernel functions by hand). I’ve succeeded in accelerating dense matrix-vector products using the cudamat library, but not for the sparse case. There are a handful of suggestions for the sparse case online, such as using pycuda, or scikit-cuda, or anaconda’s accelerate package, but there’s not a ton of information so it’s hard to know where to begin.

I don’t need greatly detailed instructions, but if anyone has solved this before and could provide a “big picture” roadmap for the simplest way of doing this, or has an idea of the sort of speed up a sparse GPU-based matrix-vector product would have over scipy’s sparse algorithms, that would be very helpful.

Comment: The CUDA cusparse library can do a spmv operation.  an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38412251/cuda-mapping-error-using-cusparse-csrmv-routine/38416537#38416537)

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is to use the `CuPy` package. It has the same interface as numpy/ scipy (wich is nice) and (for me at least), it turned out to be much easier to install than `pycuda`.
The new code would look something like this:

```
import cupy as cp
from cupyx.scipy.sparse import csr_matrix as csr_gpu

A = some_sparse_matrix #(scipy.sparse.csr_matrix)
x = some_dense_vector  #(numpy.ndarray)

A_gpu = csr_gpu(A)  #moving A to the gpu
x_gpu = cp.array(x) #moving x to the gpu

for i in range(niter):
    x_gpu = A_gpu.dot(x_gpu)
x = cp.asnumpy(x_gpu) #back to numpy object for fast indexing
```

UPDATE: cupy now supports AMD GPUs as well through their ROCm stack, so that's an added bonus

Comment: `A_gpu = csr_gpu(A)` give me `ValueError: Only bool, float32, float64, complex64 and complex128 are supported`.

Comment: what is the dtype of your matrices?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in comments, NVIDIA ship the [cuSPARSE](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html) library which includes functions for sparse matrix products with dense vectors.

Numba now has Python bindings for the cuSparse library via the [pyculib](http://pyculib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions.

I managed to get pyculib’s csrmm (matrix multiplication for compressed sparse row formatted matrices) operation to work using the following (using 2 NVIDIA K80 GPUs on Google Cloud Platform), but unfortunately wasn’t able to achieve a speedup.

I assume this is because most of the time in the csrmm function is spent transferring data to/from the GPU, as opposed to actually doing the computations. Unfortunately, I couldn’t figure out any straightforward `pyculib` way to get the arrays onto the GPU on the first place and keep them there over iterations. The code I used is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from pyculib.sparse import Sparse
from time import time


def spmv_cuda(a_sparse, b, sp, count):
    """Compute a_sparse x b."""

    # args to csrmm call
    trans_a = 'N'  # non-transpose, use 'T' for transpose or 'C' for conjugate transpose
    m = a_sparse.shape[0]  # num rows in a
    n = b.shape[1]  # num cols in b, c
    k = a_sparse.shape[1]  # num cols in a
    nnz = len(a_sparse.data)  # num nonzero in a
    alpha = 1  # no scaling
    descr_a = sp.matdescr(  # matrix descriptor
        indexbase=0,  # 0-based indexing
        matrixtype='G',  # 'general': no symmetry or triangular structure
    )
    csr_val_a = a_sparse.data  # csr data
    csr_row_ptr_a = a_sparse.indptr  # csr row pointers
    csr_col_ind_a = a_sparse.indices  # csr col idxs
    ldb = b.shape[0]
    beta = 0
    c = np.empty((m, n), dtype=a_sparse.dtype)
    ldc = b.shape[0]

    # call function
    tic = time()
    for ii in range(count):
        sp.csrmm(
            transA=trans_a,
            m=m,
            n=n,
            k=k,
            nnz=nnz,
            alpha=alpha,
            descrA=descr_a,
            csrValA=csr_val_a,
            csrRowPtrA=csr_row_ptr_a,
            csrColIndA=csr_col_ind_a,
            B=b,
            ldb=ldb,
            beta=beta,
            C=c,
            ldc=ldc)
    toc = time()

    return c, toc - tic

# run benchmark
COUNT = 20
N = 5000
P = 0.1

print('Constructing objects...\n\n')
np.random.seed(0)
a_dense = np.random.rand(N, N).astype(np.float32)
a_dense[np.random.rand(N, N) >= P] = 0
a_sparse = csr_matrix(a_dense)

b = np.random.rand(N, 1).astype(np.float32)

sp = Sparse()

# scipy sparse
tic = time()
for ii in range(COUNT):
    c = a_sparse.dot(b)
toc = time()

print('scipy sparse matrix multiplication took {} seconds\n'.format(toc - tic))
print('c = {}'.format(c[:5, 0]))

# pyculib sparse

c, t = spmv_cuda(a_sparse, b, sp, COUNT)

print('pyculib sparse matrix multiplication took {} seconds\n'.format(t))
print('c = {}'.format(c[:5, 0]))
```

which yields the output:

```
Constructing objects...

scipy sparse matrix multiplication took 0.05158638954162598 seconds

c = [ 122.29484558  127.83656311  128.75004578  130.69120789  124.98323059]

Testing pyculib sparse matrix multiplication...

pyculib sparse matrix multiplication took 0.12598299980163574 seconds

c = [ 122.29483032  127.83659363  128.75003052  130.6912384   124.98326111]
```

As you can see, pyculib is more than twice as slow, even though the matrix multiplication is on the GPU. Again, probably because of overhead involved in transferring data to/from GPU at each iteration.

An alternative solution I found, however, was to use Andreas Kloeckner’s pycuda library, which yielded a 50x speed up!

```
import numpy as np
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
from pycuda.sparse.packeted import PacketedSpMV
from pycuda.tools import DeviceMemoryPool
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from time import time


def spmv_cuda(a_sparse, b, count):

    dtype = a_sparse.dtype
    m = a_sparse.shape[0]

    print('moving objects to GPU...')

    spmv = PacketedSpMV(a_sparse, is_symmetric=False, dtype=dtype)

    dev_pool = DeviceMemoryPool()
    d_b = gpuarray.to_gpu(b, dev_pool.allocate)
    d_c = gpuarray.zeros(m, dtype=dtype, allocator=d_b.allocator)

    print('executing spmv operation...\n')

    tic = time()
    for ii in range(count):
        d_c.fill(0)
        d_c = spmv(d_b, d_c)
    toc = time()

    return d_c.get(), toc - tic


# run benchmark
COUNT = 100
N = 5000
P = 0.1
DTYPE = np.float32

print('Constructing objects...\n\n')
np.random.seed(0)
a_dense = np.random.rand(N, N).astype(DTYPE)
a_dense[np.random.rand(N, N) >= P] = 0
a_sparse = csr_matrix(a_dense)

b = np.random.rand(N, 1).astype(DTYPE)

# numpy dense
tic = time()
for ii in range(COUNT):
    c = np.dot(a_dense, b)
toc = time()

print('numpy dense matrix multiplication took {} seconds\n'.format(toc - tic))
print('c = {}\n'.format(c[:5, 0]))

# scipy sparse
tic = time()
for ii in range(COUNT):
    c = a_sparse.dot(b)
toc = time()

print('scipy sparse matrix multiplication took {} seconds\n'.format(toc - tic))
print('c = {}\n'.format(c[:5, 0]))

# pycuda sparse
c, t = spmv_cuda(a_sparse, b, COUNT)
print('pycuda sparse matrix multiplication took {} seconds\n'.format(t))
print('c = {}\n'.format(c[:5]))
```

which yields this output:

```
numpy dense matrix multiplication took 0.2290663719177246 seconds

c = [ 122.29484558  127.83656311  128.75004578  130.69120789  124.98323059]

scipy sparse matrix multiplication took 0.24468040466308594 seconds

c = [ 122.29484558  127.83656311  128.75004578  130.69120789  124.98323059]

moving objects to GPU...
executing spmv operation...

pycuda sparse matrix multiplication took 0.004545450210571289 seconds

c = [ 122.29484558  127.83656311  128.75004578  130.69120789  124.98323059]
```

Note 1: pycuda requires the following dependencies:

- pymetis: install using: `pip install pymetis`
- nvcc: install using: `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`

Note 2: for some reason `pip install pycuda` fails to install the file `pkt_build_cython.pyx`, so you’ll need to download/copy it yourself from https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/blob/master/pycuda/sparse/pkt_build_cython.pyx.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use tensorflow's matrix multiplication functions. Once GPU-enabled tensorflow is up and running, these work out-of-the-box.

After installing CUDA and tensorflow-gpu (a couple of involved but straightforward tutorials are [here](https://github.com/rkp8000/gcp_tensorflow_gpu_install_and_benchmarks) and [here](https://hackernoon.com/launch-a-gpu-backed-google-compute-engine-instance-and-setup-tensorflow-keras-and-jupyter-902369ed5272)), you can use tensorflow's SparseTensor class and sparse_tensor_dense_matmul function as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
from time import time
```

Make sure GPU is detected:

```
gpus = [x.name for x in device_lib.list_local_devices() if x.device_type == 'GPU']
print('GPU DEVICES:\n  {}'.format(gpus))
```

Output:

```
GPU DEVICES:
  ['/device:GPU:0']
```

Benchmarks:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

ITERS = 30
N = 20000
P = 0.1  # matrix density
```

Using scipy:

```
np.random.seed(0)

a_dense = np.random.rand(N, N)
a_dense[a_dense > P] = 0
a_sparse = csr_matrix(a_dense)

b = np.random.rand(N)

tic = time()
for ii in range(ITERS):
    c = a_sparse.dot(b)
toc = time()

elapsed = toc - tic

print('Scipy spmv product took {} seconds per iteration.'.format(elapsed/ITERS))
```

Output:

```
Scipy spmv product took 0.06693172454833984 seconds per iteration.
```

Using GPU-enabled tensorflow:

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):

    np.random.seed(0)

    a_dense = np.random.rand(N, N)
    a_dense[a_dense > P] = 0

    indices = np.transpose(a_dense.nonzero())
    values = a_dense[indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1]]
    dense_shape = a_dense.shape

    a_sparse = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, dense_shape)

    b = tf.constant(np.random.rand(N, 1))

    tic = time()
    for ii in range(ITERS):
        c = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(a_sparse, b)
    toc = time()

elapsed = toc - tic

print('GPU spmv product took {} seconds per iteration.'.format(elapsed/ITERS))
```

Output:

```
GPU spmv product took 0.0011811971664428711 seconds per iteration.
```

Quite a nice speed-up, it turns out.

Comment: I believe you're not really executing with this code, just creating a tensor, which is basically just book-keeping (which is why it's so fast). You would need a tf.Session() and then c.eval() to actually do the work. I tried that, and then suddenly it's not so fast anymore.