# cython float64 error although float32 specifically set

Tags: python, cython, pycuda

I am trying to implement user's @rkp [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49075520/4974969) to their own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49019189/4974969) of how to speed up sparse matrix multiplications with cython by using the `pycuda` library (please note this is their second solution in their post).

After installing `pycuda`, `pymetis` etc and running their exact same code (in IDLE Python 3.5.2) I am getting:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

It turns out the (reproducible) part that produces this error is:

```
import numpy as np
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
from pycuda.sparse.packeted import PacketedSpMV
from pycuda.tools import DeviceMemoryPool
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

COUNT = 100
N = 5000
P = 0.1
DTYPE = np.int32

#construct objects
np.random.seed(0)
a_dense = np.random.rand(N, N).astype(DTYPE)
a_dense[np.random.rand(N, N) >= P] = 0
a_sparse = csr_matrix(a_dense)

#PacketedSpMV produces the error
spmv = PacketedSpMV(a_sparse, is_symmetric=False, dtype=DTYPE)
```

And the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/svobodov/Desktop/data/tests/cython/t.py", line 23, in <module>
    spmv = PacketedSpMV(a_sparse, is_symmetric=False, dtype=DTYPE)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pycuda\sparse\packeted.py", line 185, in __init__
    local_row_costs)
  File "pkt_build_cython.pyx", line 22, in pycuda.sparse.pkt_build_cython.build_pkt_data_structure
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I initially thought this to be the cython-related double-precision error but this is obviously something different as it is expecting specifically an integer rather than `float32`..

I tried tweaking the `pkt_build_cython.pyx` but without any success or confidence that I did it properly.

Any ideas on how to resolve this please?

Comment: @Tony I doubt I'll get to the bottom of this (not sure I have CUDA set up...) but: if you look at [the relevant pyx code](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/blob/master/pycuda/sparse/pkt_build_cython.pyx) it's trying to create a zero array, so I suspect it's the size that's a float when it should be an integer. I'd guess one of `thread_count` or `max_thread_costs` is a float (probably the latter). `thread_count` comes from `pycuda.tools.DeviceData().max_threads` so that's easily investigated. `max_thread_costs` bit harder to track down. Maybe edit packeted.py to add some print statements?

Comment: @Tony if you change the pyx code then you'll need to recompile it to check the changes are taking effect. You'll probably find it easier to change the Python code that uses it instead

Comment: @DavidW thanks, will try to edit with care and see what I get out of it. Could you elaborate on your last comment please? What I am doing is simply going in the `.py` module eg. `packeted.py`, edit, and save. Does this not suffice? -edit: sorry, just realised you were taliking specifically for `.pyx`

Comment: "Changing the .py, edit then saving" works fine. If you're changing the .pyx then it needs the be process with Cython then compiled with C. That isn't too hard, but it's definitely easier just to change the .py file instead if you can.

Comment: @DavidW absolutely spot on. `max_thread_costs` comes from `max_thread_costs = np.max(thread_costs)`, and `thread_costs` is a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` of `type` `'numpy.float64'` `0.0`s

Comment: @tony Good :-) You're welcome to answer your own question here. You can probably find a short-term fix but it might be useful to submit a bug report on github to get it fixed properly

Comment: not sure if I need to do something with this question given there is no answer to accept; hopefully it will be handled by a moderator (?)

Comment: Don't think anything needs handling - there's plenty of unanswered questions hanging aroung :). My point was just that if you've come up with a solution then it's perfectly acceptable to write the answer yourself. You don't to, of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As identified in comments, this was a result of a missing integer cast within an internal routine in the PyCUDA codebase.

The bug was actually [fixed in 2018](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/commit/117afa6e863615145d11a37e047952cc0e26fe2d#diff-c46481388c76929c7d64fa369e005e33), so if you use any PyCUDA 2019 release, you should have the corrected code and this issue should not occur.