# Cupy sparse matrix does not correspond to its Scipy equivalence?

Tags: python, cupy

I digged the documentation for `cupy` sparse matrix.

as in `scipy` I expect to have something like this:

```py
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
A_csr = csr_matrix([[1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 5]])
```

but in `cupy` [here](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/v7.8.0/reference/sparse.html#:%7E:text=To%20convert%20CuPy%20ndarray%20to,sparse.):

> To convert CuPy ndarray to CuPy sparse matrices, pass it to the constructor of each CuPy sparse matrix class.

```py
# from cupy.sparse import csr_matrix as cp_csr_matrix
from cupyx.scipy.sparse import csr_matrix as cp_csr_matrix

cA = cp.array([[1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 5]])
cA_csr = cp_csr_matrix(cA)
```

return :

```sh
ValueError: Only bool, float32, float64, complex64 and complex128 are supported
```

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57180795/784433) answer which give the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as stated in the error, you need to convert the datatype to either bool, float32/64, or complex64/128:

```py
import cupy as cp
from cupyx.scipy.sparse import csr_matrix as cp_csr_matrix

cA = cp.array([[1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 5]], dtype=cp.float32)
cA_csr = cp_csr_matrix(cA)
```

BTW, can you please try `cA.astype(cp.float64)` on your machine and see if there are errors? Mine will throw an `NVRTCError`. Weird...

Comment: I tried that on `colab`, got no error.